# Android Studio - mystery keyboard shortcut to list all named parameters with autocomplete using "Opt P" (on Mac)

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, jetbrains-ide, intellij-14

I'm trying to find an equivalent of <kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd> (Windows shortcut) in VS Code to list all named parameters in Android Studio. I know <kbd>CMD + P</kbd> (Mac) will show a popup with all parameters.

I found that <kbd>Opt + P</kbd> (Mac) will list all parameters similar to the VS Code shortcut.

However, <kbd>Opt + P</kbd> maps to "π" on mac keyboards so it puts a π in front of any names parameter I select from the list even if I used `Tab`, `Space`, or `Enter`.

I have the Presenter plugin installed to show what shortcut is being called when I press <kbd>Opt + P</kbd> and it doesn't register any shortcuts. When I look through all the keyboard shortcut options in Android Studio I don't see anything bound to <kbd>Opt + P</kbd> so I can't reassign it to a key that won't result in a π.

[Android Studio Key mapping](https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf)

Any ideas?

Opt + P result Image:
[image: opt+P result Image]

Comment: The `Keymap` Settings screen has "Find Action by Shortcut" button (the one next to the local search field). Use it to locate the needed action: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-keymap.html#267d2b7f

Comment: @LazyOne. I've searched there already and the Opt+p shortcut does not exist in the keymap options. But it works in the editor...

Comment: No other ideas from me, sorry. It could be something Mac-specific. **P.S.** Still, `Main Menu | Code | Completion` (or something like that) -- check all actions one by one there and see if any of them will show a similar popup.